# What is the maximum channel capacity allowed on the Bitcoin testnet?

Tags: electrum, testnet, ln-opening-channels

Using Electrum desktop wallet connected to the testnet, when trying to open a channel  with the amount exceeding 0.16777215 BTC I get the following:

> Could not open channel. Exception('Requested channel capacity is over protocol allowed maximum')

Is 0.16777215 BTC hardcoded in Electrum or is it determined by the testnet itself?
I noticed that on the mainnet the maximum capacity is siginificatly higher as some exchanges allow LN withdrawals of 0.5 BTC.

Answer (score 1):

> Is 0.16777215 BTC hardcoded in Electrum or is it determined by the testnet itself?

There's no such hard coded value in Electrum. The limit is imposed by the [Lightning protocol](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/b201efe0546120c14bf154ce5f4e18da7243fe7a/02-peer-protocol.md#requirements-9):

> for channels with `chain_hash` identifying the Bitcoin blockchain, if the four most significant bytes of `amount_msat` are not 0:
> MUST fail the channel.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that on the mainnet the maximum capacity is siginificatly higher as some exchanges allow LN withdrawals of 0.5 BTC

I think they are using wumbo channels:

[Is the Lightning Network sufficiently secure and well tested for wumbo channels?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99172/)